# Custom magento 2 theme not showing up up on content/design/configuration

Tags: magento2, template, custom

I have been trying for two day to figure out how I can customize my magento template. Recently I have become stuck on being able to  pull up my new magento theme in the backend admin panel. I have followed the the dev docs to the tee, at least I think so, but I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are the files

**Registration.php:**

```
<?php
 

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/shayan/uub',
__DIR__
);
```

**theme.xml:**

```
<!--

    <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento uub</title>
    <parent>boxstore/boxstore_default</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**composer.json**:

```
    {
       "name": "shayan/theme-frontend-uub",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
   }
```

I have already tried

```
php cache:clear php
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Closing tag of theme is missing in the given code..could u try adding it in theme.xml and give a try

Comment: change  <parent>boxstore/boxstore_default</parent> to " <parent>Magento/blank</parent>" in theme.xml:

Answer (score 0):

Add or copy from an existing theme.xml to your theme directory app/design/frontend//

Configure it using the following example:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
 </media>
```

If you change the theme title or parent theme information in theme.xml after a theme was already registered, you need to open or reload any Magento Admin page for your changes to be saved in the database.

Reference Link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to camel case the first character of vendor name like 
**'frontend/shayan/uub'** it should be **'frontend/Shayan/uub'**

Answer (score 0):

I too faced with this issue and below is the solution worked for me:

I observed that running:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
```

Gave below result:

> Design Config Grid index is locked by another reindex process.
>   Skipping.

So to get that fixed i ran:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
```

And this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the theme **boxstore/boxstore_default** appears in your database. If not yet, please add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 change <parent>boxstore/boxstore_default</parent> to " <parent>Magento/blank</parent>" in theme.xml
```

and run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clear
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```